# dovecot/sendmail settings to proxytunnel imap/smtp to gmail servers from behind a proxy?

Tags: gmail, imap, tunnel, smtp, http-proxy

I am trying to set up a tunnel to access my gmail account from a system behind a proxy/firewall.

I came across the [proxytunnel](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/paper.php) based solution. The solution requires local imap/smtp servers to be set up.

How to set up `dovecot` and `sendmail` so that they correctly tunnel the imap/smtp requests to the gmail servers using the proxytunnel?